# Have WebDriverManager use pre-downloaded chrome-driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

For linux boxes that are not able to download chrome-driver to local, how can I specify a local version to be used with WebDriverManager ? I see that targetPath() is not available to define where the driver is located.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("120.0.6099.71").targetPath(pathToPreDownloadedDriver).setup();
```

Comment: why not can download webdriver to linux?

Answer (score 0):

If you have manually downloaded chromedriver, instead of WebDriverManager, you can use the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```